# Issue with javascript - stops working after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues with my javascript on a particular page. This is very weird.

http://www.rayku.com/tutorshelp

How it is supposed to work is fetch from an external html file every time I flip through the tabs on the right. However, after 3 seconds, it just stops working. It doesn't matter how many times you flip before the 3 seconds (or any for that matter). After the 3 seconds, it just stops flipping.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see 3 different versions of jQuery *and* Prototype being loaded I don't know if you loaded jQuery in noconflict mode but that would definitely be the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, keep an eye on your web console, it will alert you of these types of issues.
When you click on a tab the console reads:

`tutorshelp-ajax.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of null`

If you go to line 9 you'll see: `$('#video-content').load('/help-external/video'+step+'.html');`

Since the message is cannot call method 'load' of 'null' it means that $('#video-content') is null.

This is happening because they are not wrapped in [$(document).ready();](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and they are being set up before the `video-content` id even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Dev tools are your friend...

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of null"

on line 9 in:

http://www.rayku.com/js/tutorshelp-ajax.js

You are also including scripts twice. I would look into that.